# Microsoft accounts

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

I have a Microsoft account (@outlook.com) and an Orgainizational account (@mycompany.com)
I find that Office 365 and SharePoint routinely get confused between them.

I'm currently trying to login to a SharePoint site with my Organizational account, and it keeps going to 'You need permission to access this site' page.

I've logout out of SharePoint many times and shut the browser, but every time I go back to the site it thinks I'm trying to use my Microsoft account.

What gives??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your organization has a single sign-on app, reinstall it. I have seen this behavior before for SSO. Also make sure in your 365 top right corner that your organization account is selected, not your Microsoft account. Any Office product in 365, I normally change it in word.